# Firestore getAll equivalent for Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, algolia

Is it a `getAll` equivalent to nodejs function in Android.
I'm looking to retrieve all documents from an ids list that was sent back from a live search service (Algolia or Elasticsearch).

ps:
I'm not interested in Algolia instantsearch as it doesn't implement (yet, I guess) live data retrieving as firestore do.

Comment: There currently is none for mobile clients.

Comment: I found this thread when I was looking for an answer, but the last answer was from 2017, I hope more positive news for 2019. It's an non-useless feature as Firestore doesn't permit fulltext search and Google points us to third-party tools to do that, we need to retrieve back our data when a search is performed.

Comment: You're always free to file a feature request.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features